# Can't build app on release mode Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I keep getting this error when I try to run the app on release mode:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
> Can't resolve the reference 'System.Void
> System.Security.Cryptography.DSACng::.ctor(System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey)',
> referenced from the method 'T
> Internal.Cryptography.Pal.Windows.PkcsPalWindows::GetPrivateKey(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2,System.Boolean,System.Boolean)'
> in 'System.Security.Cryptography.Cng, Version=4.3.3.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. LabelApp.iOS

I see on the internet that it is related to mailkit, however, I deleted all references to mailkit. On android, everything works fine and even on debug mode it works fine.

I already tried removing the references to mailkit and used older and newer versions of mailkit. I expected that the error would be resolved because this worked on another app I made in the past, but it didn't.

Comment: Did You try to set Linker Behaviour to "Don't Link" in IOS project settings?

Comment: Yes I did, in debug mode this works, but in release mode I get other errors because not everything is linked.

Comment: Check nuget for System.Security.Cryptography.X509, You should have it only in this shared project and for example my version is 4.3.2 that is latest stable. Maybe You have some references in project as well to ios?

Comment: I fixed it. It seems that the problem was with a package called EPPlus which I used to export data to an excel file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it. It seems that the problem was with a package called EPPlus which I used to export data to an excel file.